# Adding editable field to ASP.NET MVC Account model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble editing a field I have added to my account model in asp.net MVC's account model. I can create and access this field just fine, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to edit it. The value I want to be able to edit is "UserInputTwo"

Here is what my model for it looks like now:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FID { get; set; }
    public string UserInputTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my attempt that the View so far, but no luck:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account")) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Change Info Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserInputTwo)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInputTwo)
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Change password" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

edit: here's the controller:

```
    public ActionResult EditInfo(string user)
    {
        ViewBag.User = user;
            return View();
    }


     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditInfo(UserProfile UserProfile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(UserProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
```

Comment: Might be helpful to see the action you're posting to

Comment: What's the error msg you're seeing

Comment: Well it takes me to the "manage" page and says "•The Current password field is required.
•The New password field is required.
"

Comment: This line does absolutely nothing:  `UserProfile.UserInputTwo = UserProfile.UserInputTwo;`

Comment: Yeah it was just a placeholder for the code I had copied from which was like: x.user = z or something like that, just kept it in there to make it easy to change later. took it out for now.

Comment: what is the model being used on the top of the cshtml page? Is it UserProfile?

Comment: @model FTv2.Models.UserProfile

Comment: add this line in your view  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)